# what is the big o notation of while false loop?

Tags: java, while-loop, time-complexity, big-o

I am really struggling to calculate the big O notation of this piece of code.

```
Boolean validInput = false;
while (validInput == false) {
    System.out.println("Please input number of cards");
    if (stdin.hasNextInt()) {
        n = stdin.nextInt();
        if (n > 0) {
            validInput = true;
        } else {
            System.out.println("INVALID INPUT: INPUT MUST BE STRICTLY POSITIVE INTEGER");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("INVALID INPUT: INPUT MUST BE STRICTLY POSITIVE INTEGER");
        stdin.next();
    }
}
```

Comment: `O(n)` where `n` is the number of wrong inputs.

Comment: @tkausl the asymptotical runtime should be a worst-case analysis based on the input of the algorithm. This algorithm has no input. If the user enters only incorrect inputs or never enters anything, the algorithm does not terminate.

Comment: I would argue this code has no time complexity. At least no sensible one, you could argue it is constant, you could argue it is linear, it really makes no sense or difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Comment: @AlexRudenko I do not think that this is a useful duplicate since it does not mention algorithms that do not satisfy the property of finiteness.

Answer (score 2):

Time complexity is a sensible property of an algorithm [iff.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) the algorithms does terminate (Finiteness).

The algorithm shown does not terminate: a user may only enter invalid inputs, or a user may never enter anything at all. It has no time complexity.